# CombineDeletedEntities/SeparateDeletedEntities Adding Duplicate Entities

Tags: c#, invalidoperationexception, entityspaces

I have a grid with the datasource set to an [EntitySpaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EntitySpaces) collection, with a checkbox column. When the checkbox is checked, I want to create a record and when it is cleared I want to delete the same record.

To avoid the obvious [PK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#Primary_key) violation save if a user repeatedly checks and unchecks an item, I am trying to retrieve the previously deleted entities and mark them as not deleted. However, when I use `CombineDeletedEntities` and `SeparateDeletedEntities` on the collection it creates duplicate entries in the collection.

```
roleFunctions.CombineDeletedEntities();

// On third cycle through, this is the error line
RoleFunction foundItem = roleFunctions.FindByPrimaryKey(roleName, functionName);

if (foundItem != null) 
{
    foundItem.RowState = esDataRowState.Unchanged;

    // Extraneous logic...
}
else
{
    // Create new item...
}

roleFunctions.SeparateDeletedEntities();
```

So basically when I do `FindByPrimaryKey` the third time, EntitySpaces has created an extra item somehow which causes an `InvalidOperationException` with a message of `Sequence contains more than one matching element`.

Has anyone hit this with EntitySpaces before and how did you end up nicely handling a user creating and deleting the same entity multiple times in a single session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a fairly easy fix, especially since EntitySpaces is open source. The two methods I was using to avoid creating duplicate records are shown below:

```
public override void CombineDeletedEntities()
{
    if (this.deletedEntities != null && this.deletedEntities.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (T entity in deletedEntities)
        {
            entities.Add(entity);
        }
    }
}

public override void SeparateDeletedEntities()
{
    foreach (T entity in this.entities)
    {
        if (entity.rowState == esDataRowState.Deleted)
        {
            if (deletedEntities == null)
            {
                deletedEntities = new BindingList<T>();
            }

            deletedEntities.Add(entity);
        }
    }

    if (this.deletedEntities != null && this.deletedEntities.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (T entity in deletedEntities)
        {
            entities.Remove(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the above it becomes fairly obvious that the code will continue adding back the same entities into the `deletedEntities` list every time we call `SeparateDeletedEntities`.

The easy solution was to clear the `deletedEntities` collection when the are combined with the collection proper:

```
public override void CombineDeletedEntities()
{
    if (this.deletedEntities != null && this.deletedEntities.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (T entity in deletedEntities)
        {
            entities.Add(entity);
        }

        this.deletedEntities.Clear();
    }
}
```

The downside to this quick and dirty fix is that you probably don't want to call `collection.Save()` after calling `CombineDeletedEntities` until you have called `SeparateDeletedEntities`, since having an empty `deletedEntities` collection will probably cause your save to skip all deletes.

I would have liked to just add a `if (!deletedEntities.Contains(entity))` call in the `SeparateDeletedEntities` routine, but the equality comparison sees the entities as different so I went with the simpler solution.